How can I give custom validation attribute for the model property
I have a three column ScheduleDate,RegistrationDate, SalesTargetHrs for the CustomerSales modal.How can I validate  ScheduleDate must be greater than SalesTargetHrs and RegistrationDate. For example Registration Date is '2024-07-24 11:23:45'  and SalesTargetHrs is 72 hrs , then the ScheduleDate should be greater than that of the date of RegistrationDate after adding SalesTargetHrs. How can I show custom validation attribute and error message 'Scheduled greater than expected targeted Date'
public class CustomerSales()
{
   public DateTime RegistrationDate {get;set;}
   public DateTime ScheduleDate{get;set;}
   public int SalesTargetHrs {get;set;}
}


According to your description, you could create a validate attritbue to achieve your requirement. You could get the post model inside the attribute validate method, then you could compare them.
More details, you could refer to below codes:
Class:
public class CustomerSales
{
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    [ScheduleDateValidation]
    public DateTime ScheduleDate { get; set; }

    public int SalesTargetHrs { get; set; }
}

Validate attribute:
public class ScheduleDateValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var customerSales = (CustomerSales)validationContext.ObjectInstance;


        DateTime targetDate = customerSales.RegistrationDate.AddHours(customerSales.SalesTargetHrs);

     
        if (customerSales.ScheduleDate <= targetDate)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Scheduled greater than expected targeted Date");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}

Create method:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(CustomerSales model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
     }
    else
    {
        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors)
                               .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)
                               .ToList();
        // Handle the validation errors
    }

    return View(model);
}

Result:


